# the best constant in an inequality?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

I learnt how to show the below inequality by C-S inequality: k is from $0$ to $\infty$

If $\sum a_{k}^{2}9^{k}\le 5$ then $\sum |a_{k}|2^{k}\le 3$.

next,I tried to show that 3 is the best possible constant in the last inequality.

Could you please help me to show how 3 is the best possible constant.

Comment: Can you see what happens when the inequality on the left is an equality?

Comment: What is the range of $k$?

Comment: Also, would you explain how you showed your claim?

Comment: $k$ must range from $0$ to $\infty$, for this claim to be true. Presumably you used Cauchy-Schwarz for your proof. Do you know under what circumstance the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is in fact an equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** *If $\omega>1$, and $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb R$, then
$$
(\omega^2-1)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert b_k\rvert\Big)^2\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \omega^{2k}b^2_k,
$$
and $\omega^2-1$ is the optimal constant.*

*Proof.* Using Cauchy-Schwarz (which is a special case for Hölder's inequality for $p=q=2$) we obtain
\begin{align}
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N \lvert b_k\rvert\Big)^2&=
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N \omega^{-k}\big(\omega^{k}\lvert b_k\rvert\big)\Big)^2
\le \Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{-2k}\Big)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big) \\&=\frac{\omega^{-2}-\omega^{-2N}}{1-\omega^{-2}}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big) \le \frac{\omega^{-2}}{1-\omega^{-2}}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big) \\&=\frac{1}{\omega^{2}-1}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big)\le \frac{1}{\omega^{2}-1}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big).
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N\omega^{-2k}\Big)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big) \le
(\omega^{2}-1)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\omega^{2k}b_k^2\Big). \tag*{$\Box$}
$$

In our case, $\omega=3/2$ and $b_k=2^ka_k$: 
$$
5\ge\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^2_k9^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2^ka_k)^2(3^k/2^k)^2\ge \Big((3/2)^2-1\Big)
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k\lvert a_k\rvert\Big)^2=\frac{5}{4}
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k\lvert a_k\rvert\Big)^2.
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}2^k\lvert a_k\rvert\ \le 2,
$$
and $2$ is the best estimate.

Comment: thank you. is there a book you can recommend that i can learn these kind of inequalities.

Comment: This inequality is definitely not a standard one. I came up to it up, using Lagrange multipliers. The inverse direction is more common, as it is related to Cauchy-Schwarz. The only books I would recommend are those related to Math Contests.

Comment: our prof wants us to use the condition when hölder inequality holds for equality. i ve tried to solve it. but the $a_{k}$ I derive does not work. could you please help with this approach. i have tried so hard to figure it out. frustated... but then would not it contradict with your result $\le 2$. i am a bit confused

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_k=3^ka_k$, then Cauchy-Schwarz says
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^na_k2^k
&=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\left(\frac23\right)^k\\
&\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac49\right)^k\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^29^k\right)^{1/2}\frac2{\sqrt5}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac49\right)^n}\\
&=2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac49\right)^n}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Note that equality holds in $(5)$ when $b_k=\lambda\left(\frac23\right)^k$ for some lambda; that is, when $a_k=\lambda\left(\frac29\right)^k$. This gives us
$$
a_k=\frac{\frac52}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac49\right)^n}}\left(\frac29\right)^k\tag{6}
$$
which shows that $(5)$ is sharp.